# How to log additional data with slf4j?

Tags: slf4j, log4j2

I want to add additinal data to my logs. Currently I am using MDC but problem is when I add any additional data to MDC, my all other logs are also saved with these MDC values. (I think its because of they all sharing same thread)

Is there any way to clean MDC after org.slf4j.Logger debug method?

Here is my logger code;

```
public void debug(String message) {
    logger.debug(addAdditionalDatas(message)); //org.slf4j.Logger
}

public void addAdditionalDatas(String message) {
    MDC.put("param", value);
    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add it manually, you can manually remove it like this:

```
MDC.remove("param");
```